# Elastic-search 7.7 service not getting started

Tags: sites-9.1, elasticsearch

Installing Elastic-search 7.7 service not getting started we are are getting following error

```
Error "the system property [es.path.conf] must be set" when starting the service registered
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After Investigating the elastic search logs (path: `c:\elasticsearch-7.7.0\logs\elasticsearch-service-x64-stderr.YYYY-MM-dd`)

```
Error "the system property [es.path.conf] must be set" when starting the service registered
```

Refer to the [link](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/61333) for the fix

Solution:

```
The fix provided here [#57769][2] doesn't help since the culprit is not the same variable, I had to add the line
if not "%OTHER_JAVA_OPTS%" == "" set OTHER_JAVA_OPTS=%OTHER_JAVA_OPTS:;;=;%
before calling "%EXECUTABLE%" (after line 205) to file elasticsearch-service.bat
```

Hope this will help if anyone face a similar issue.